# How to Use Persian Date Picker in a Android Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, fragment

i want to use [this](https://github.com/aliab/Persian-Date-Picker-Dialog) `Persian Date Picker Dialog` in a `Fragment` but i can't use it whit `Dialog Fragment`.
Can anybody help me???

Comment: Please provide a little code what are you trying to do or where are your errors so we can help you, without anything giving we are not able to help you, please read minimal requirements of question at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as he said Spritzig for next questions u must provide more info and example code...

I test the library in a Fragment and works, here the code i use:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, container, false);

    PersianDatePickerDialog picker = new PersianDatePickerDialog(getActivity())
            .setPositiveButtonString("باشه")
            .setNegativeButton("بیخیال")
            .setTodayButton("امروز")
            .setTodayButtonVisible(true)
            .setMaxYear(PersianDatePickerDialog.THIS_YEAR)
            .setMinYear(1300)
            .setActionTextColor(Color.GRAY)
            .setListener(new Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSelected(PersianCalendar persianCalendar) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), persianCalendar.getPersianYear() + "/" + persianCalendar.getPersianMonth() + "/" + persianCalendar.getPersianDay(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDismissed() {

                }
            });

    picker.show();

    return rootView;
}
```

Replace the reference to "this" when u instantiate PersianDatePickerDialog with a reference to Activity:

```
PersianDatePickerDialog picker = new PersianDatePickerDialog(getActivity())
```

Regards!